# Abrir una URL en segundo plano

Tags: java, zk

Tengo un método para crear dinámicamente objetos de tipo MenuItem en función de una lista de operaciones que tengo creada.Dentro de ese método tengo el siguiente bucle FOR:

```
     for(OperacionConfigurableDTO oc : this.plantillaPrincipalFichaPacienteVM.getListaOperacionesConfigurables()){
            if(comprobarEstado(oc) && comprobarPerfil(oc) && comprobarActiva(oc)){
                Menuitem m = new Menuitem();

                AImage imagen = null;
                try {
                    imagen = new AImage("", oc.getIcono());
                    m.setImageContent(imagen);
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                m.setImageContent(imagen);
                m.setTooltiptext(oc.getNombre());
                m.setStyle("text-align: center;");
                m.setWidth("50px");

                m.addEventListener("onClick",new EventListener<MouseEvent>(){
                     @Override
                      public void onEvent(MouseEvent event) throws Exception {
                            System.out.println("PULSADO BOTON");

                     }
                });
                menuOpciones.appendChild(m);
                contadorOperaciones++;

            }   
    }
```

Dentro de ese onClick que estoy creando para cada elemento(ya que MenuItem de ZK no lo trae), necesito ejecutar una URL, pero en segundo plano, sin que se abra una nueva pestaña en mi navegador(por si quiero hacer una llamada a un servicio). Pero después de un buen tiempo de intentos no lo consigo, solo me sale llamar a la URL abriendo una nueva pestaña.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No conozco el framework que mencionas pero podés crear un runnable para correrlo desde otro Thread y  que te avise cuando finalizó.

```
class BuscarUrl implements Runnable{
   BuscarUrl.Listener callbackListener;

   public BuscarUrl(Listener cbListener){
       this.callbackListener = cbListener;
   }

   @Override
   public void run(){
       try{
         URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
         HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         con .setRequestMethod("GET");
         con .setDoOutput(true);
         con.connect();
         InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

         // Aca leer la respuesta del input stream 

         callbackListener.finOk(); //Se podria agregar un parametro si querés pasar un resultado
       }catch(Exception e){ 
          e.printstacktrace();
          callbackListener.finConError(e);
       }
   }

   public static interface Listener {
        public void finOK();
        public void finConError(Exception e);
   }
}
```

Luego:

```
m.addEventListener("onClick",new EventListener<MouseEvent>(){
                 @Override
                  public void onEvent(MouseEvent event) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("PULSADO BOTON");
                        BuscarUrl.Listener listener = new BuscarUrl.Listener(){
                               // impelemntar los métodos de callback
                        }
                        new Thread(new BuscarUrl(listener)).start();
                 }
});
```

Ojo que el callback, se ejecuta en otro Thread y muchos frameworks tiene un thread específico para actualizar la interfaz de usuario. Es decir que prbablemente no puedas actualizar la pantalla desde el callback.

También es comúm que dichos frameworks incluyan una función para actualizar la interfaz de usuaro desde otros thread (ejemplo runOnUiThread(), o nombres similares), si fuera el caso dede el callback tendrias que usar esta función.

El código no lo probé por lo que puede tener algún error.

Comment: Tenía algún error como dices, pero me sirvió para sacar rápido la solución, muchas gracias!